# How to empty an array and create a new array with select data

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to get info from an output array. And I want to make a new array with new indexes to reference, but only if the $history_type != 'Fee'.
The code i have here only creates one listing in the array. I want it to store each of the while loops if the $history_type != 'Fee';
Here is what i have.

```
//History data grid
$i = 0;
$idx = 1;
while ($i <= 19):
    $history_date = $history[result][$i][Date];
    $history_date_format = gmdate("m-d-y", $history_date);      
    $history_type = $history[result][$i][Type];
    if($history_type == 'spent'):
        $history_type = 'Buy';
        elseif($history_type == 'earned'):
            $history_type = 'Sold';
        elseif ($history_type == 'fee'):
            $history_type = 'Fee';
        else:
            $history_type = 'Error';
    endif;
    $history_usd = $history[result][$i][Balance][value];
    $history_btc = $history[result][$i][Trade][Amount][value];
    $history_amt = $history[result][$i][Value][value];
    $history_rate = round($history_amt / $history_btc,2);
    if($history_type != 'Fee'):
        $history_array = array($idx, $history_type, $history_rate, $history_amt, $history_usd, $history_btc, $history_date_format);
        $idx++;
        //echo '<tr><td>'.$history_type.'</td><td>'.$history_rate.'</td><td>'.$history_amt.'</td><td>'.$history_usd.'</td><td>'.$history_btc.'</td><td>'.$history_date_format.'</td></tr>';
    endif;

print_r($history_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
    $history_array = array($idx, $history_type, $history_rate, $history_amt, $history_usd, $history_btc, $history_date_format);
```

to

```
$history_array[] = array($idx, $history_type, $history_rate, $history_amt, $history_usd, $history_btc, $history_date_format);
```

this

Comment: Are you serious?!? I simply missed the []. awesome.
What do they mean or signify?

Comment: Actually i'm not seeing a change in my output. Does 'print_r($history_array);' work to print out the array? I tried 'var_dump($history_array);' too.

Comment: keep print_r outside while and [] will append result array into multi dimentional array